# mongodb database recovery script

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

I'm using the below sh script with cron in order to save a backup for my database. Recently i add a DbOwner on the "db" database and dump is not working. My question is, how can i add the new database DbOwner username and password that's will allow read/write on the database.

Many thanks in advance !!

```
#!/bin/bash

MONGO_DATABASE="db"
APP_NAME="app"
MONGO_USERNAME="test"
MONGO_PASSWORD="test"

MONGO_HOST="127.0.0.1"
MONGO_PORT="27017"
TIMESTAMP=`date +%F-%H%M`
MONGODUMP_PATH="/usr/bin/mongodump"
BACKUPS_DIR="/home/test/backup/$APP_NAME"
BACKUP_NAME="$APP_NAME-$TIMESTAMP"

# mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncLock())"
# $MONGODUMP_PATH -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -d $MONGO_DATABASE
$MONGODUMP_PATH -d $MONGO_DATABASE
# mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncUnlock())"

mkdir -p $BACKUPS_DIR
mv dump $BACKUP_NAME
tar -zcvf $BACKUPS_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME.tgz $BACKUP_NAME
rm -rf $BACKUP_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created your DbOwner with username *test* and password *test*, and granted it readWrite privileges

```
[
  {
    "user" : "test",
    "db" : "db",
    "roles" : [ 
      {
        "role" : "readWrite",
        "db" : "db"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

then you just need to specify *username* and *password* arguments to mongodump:

```
$MONGODUMP_PATH -u $MONGO_USERNAME -p $MONGO_PASSWORD -d $MONGO_DATABASE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i'm going to test it and i will come ack to you !!